# Error in xml file while creating a project in black berry

Tags: blackberry

I just created a new project in the eclipse and as soon as it was created, it is created with the error below

```
InvalidRegex:
Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid
regular expression.
The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range.
Write '\-'.' at column '{2}'.
BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml Unknown XML Problem.
```

This is the problem which we will get when there is jre7 in our system which is not supported by eclipse

[image]

What is the problem here? How can i rectify this? thank you

Comment: The actual content of your `Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml` file would be much more helpful in finding the problem than this screenshot.

Comment: But there is nothing to see in it. I didnt create the file. It is automatically created by eclipse

Comment: Well obviously eclipse is unhappy about something in this file and if you expect us to help we need to see it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you are interested in seeing?

Comment: If I have a free wish I'd like this screenshot replaced by the actual error message so this question can by found by others facing the same problem.

Comment: InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'.' at column '{2}'.    BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml       Unknown    XML Problem. This is the problem which we will get when there is jre7 in our system which is not supported by eclipse

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4174/discussion-between-user609282-and-filburt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google shows this is related to Java 7. Check these two links:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/problem-with-the-BlackBerry-App-Descriptor-xml-in-Eclipse-Plug/td-p/959029 and http://cdrussell.blogspot.com/2011/09/blackberry-eclipse-error-invalid-regex.html

The second one tells:

> Turns out this could be caused by having Java JRE 7 installed on your
>   machine. The BlackBerry plugin doesn't support this yet, Eclipse might
>   be trying to use that.
>
> The fix? You simply have to edit the eclipse.ini that will live in the
>   same directory as your eclipse.exe that you use to start the IDE.
>   Closing Eclipse and making a backup of eclipse.ini before you do this
>   would be a good idea.
>
> Find the line "openFile" and immediately after, add the following:
>
> -vm C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/javaw.exe [or wherever your jre6 directory might be]
>
> Cross your fingers and restart Eclipse. Rebuild your projects.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It's the problem with jre7. It is working fine with jre6